# sending multiple attachment using uuencode

Tags: shell-script, mail-command

I want to send multiple CSV file using below code. In Result folder, we have multiple CSV files. However, I want to catch only Summary CSV files.
I was trying using *, % with different combination. However, not able to do so.

From below code, I could send only one file (SDN_WCFINCEN_summary_20151013_111216.csv )

```
(cat /aceapp/QATD011R4/ace.ofac/testofac/results/SDN_WCFINCEN_summary_20151013_111216.csv;
uuencode /aceapp/QATD011R4/ace.ofac/testofac/results/SDN_WCFINCEN_summary_20151013_111216.csv SDN_WCFINCEN_summary_20151013_111216.csv) | mail -s "Summary Report" smawle@acesw.com
```

Comment: `uuencode` can't handle multiple file, moreover, `uuencode a b` will encode `a` with `b` as a name, you have to do a loop.

Answer (score 1):

As Archemar says, you need a loop.  For example:

(BTW, add as many files as you like to the FILES variable, separated by spaces)

```
FILES="/aceapp/QATD011R4/ace.ofac/testofac/results/SDN_WCFINCEN_summary_20151013_111216.csv"

(for f in $FILES ; do uuencode "$f" "$f" ; done ) | mail -s "Summary Report" smawle@acesw.com
```

If you want to strip the path from the filename output by uuencode, replace the second `"$f"` in the `uuencode` command with `$(basename "$f")`

Comment: Why are you looping over a single value?

Comment: @Wildcard the OP says to add the list of files to `$FILES`. The example is of only one file though

Comment: If the OP hadn't specified `uuencode`, I would preferred to use a tool like `mime-construct` or `makemime` or write a trivial script using one of the perl or python MIME mail generating modules.     BTW,  looking at my answer again, if I could have assumed bash rather than sh, I would have used an array for FILES rather than a string.  and to make a more useful script, maybe extracted the date/time from the .csv filename and added that to the Subject: header (either with bash string manipulation features or with sed) - but only if sending only one file at a time.

Comment: @Wildcard why?  read the second, parenthetical, paragraph of my answer and then read the question again.